# How can I create a System Mutex in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

How can I create a system/multiprocess Mutex to co-ordinate multiple processes using the same unmanaged resource.

Background: 
  I've written a procedure that uses a File printer, which can only be used by one process at a time.  If I wanted to use it on multiple programs running on the computer, I'd need a way to synchronize this across the system.

Comment: Here's a wrapped class that handles inter process locking and abandoned mutex conditions https://github.com/blinemedical/Inter-process-mutex

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a constructor overload for checking for an existing mutex.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=vs.90).aspx

So...

```
void doWorkWhileHoldingMutex()
{
    Console.WriteLine("   Sleeping...");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

var requestInitialOwnership = true;
bool mutexWasCreated;
Mutex m = new Mutex(requestInitialOwnership, 
         "MyMutex", out mutexWasCreated);

if (requestInitialOwnership && mutexWasCreated)
{
    Console.WriteLine("We own the mutex");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mutex was created, but is not owned. Waiting on it...");
    m.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("Now own the mutex.");
}
doWorkWhileHoldingMutex();
Console.WriteLine("Finished working. Releasing mutex.");
m.ReleaseMutex();
```

If you fail to call `m.ReleaseMutex()` it will be called 'abandoned' when your thread exits. When another thread constructs the mutex, the exception `System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException` will be thrown telling him it was found in the abandoned state.

Comment: The .NET Framework 4.5 added the [`TryOpenExisting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194641.aspx) method which does not throw an exception if the mutex does not already exist.

Comment: @280Z28 Thanks for the reminder. The .NET fx 3.5 has an equivalent capability (although I argue that it has a design flaw) which I didn't mention in my original answer and which I illustrated above in EDIT TWO.

Comment: Just a small (but important) detail, the Mutex is abandoned when the thread, not the process, ends. In my case I had a WCF service with multiple threads and one of them was abandoning the mutex enabling multiple instances to run simultaneously. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception.aspx

Comment: it's kind of a mess. Your last example actually only "does work" if it didn't create the mutex, and there is no "Release" method on Mutex. But it gets idea across.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`System.Threading.Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) class, which has an [`OpenExisting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.openexisting.aspx) method to open a named system mutex.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that method was what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had good luck using the System Mutex described above using Mono under Linux.  I'm probably just doing something simple wrong but the following works well and cleans up nicely if the process exits unexpectedly (kill -9 ).  Would would be interested to hear comments or critisisms.

```
class SocketMutex{
    private Socket _sock;
    private IPEndPoint _ep;
    public SocketMutex(){
        _ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse( "127.0.0.1" ), 7177);
        _sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        _sock.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;  // most critical if you want this to be a system wide mutex
    }

    public bool GetLock(){
        try{        
            _sock.Bind(_ep); // 'SocketException: Address already in use'
        }catch(SocketException se){
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("SocketMutex Exception: " se.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```