# Object synchronization exception with background task Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mutex, background-process

I'm getting the following exception when my Windows Phone 8 background scheduled task runs. When inititialising the Mutex I've tried the first argument as false and true, but each time it runs there's always an exception thrown. The work my agent carries out is successful. I need to use a Mutex as the agent will access my SQLite database and I need to block any concurrent access to the database from the foreground app itself. Am I missing something? It's my understanding using a named Mutex will act as system wide and what I'm trying to do should work.

```
       {System.Exception: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
        at System.Threading.Mutex.ReleaseMutex()
        at MyScheduledTaskAgent.ScheduledAgent.<OnInvoke>d__2.MoveNext()}


    protected async override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        using (Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, "SQLiteMutex"))
        {
            try
            {
                await SchedAgent.ProcessUpdate();

                if (Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Comment: Since it is a system wide Mutex have you tried the solution in this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186747/how-can-i-create-a-system-mutex-in-c-sharp

Comment: Having done some more reading it seems that it's because I'm calling await on my update function... I'm doing that as my SQLite code runs with async, I'm hoping that if remove the await/async keywords it'll work, since it's the background task it can all run synchronously, then I'll need to change my app too but that needs to run asynchronously, I saw a post talking about using a SemaphoreSlim instead...

Comment: Although it won't be as simple as just removing the async/await keywords I don't think. How can I force it run synchronously?

Comment: As far as I can tell you will never be able to achieve that with Mutex. You could start the async code in a seperate thread, but considering the fact that the async code is the one you want to protect the Mutex wouldn't be doing anything then.

Comment: Async/Await confirmed. Just replaced: await MyFunc(); with MyFunc.Wait(); and problem gone .