# How to not open multiple windows at the same time for CAM interface

Tags: c#, winforms, button, plugins

I'm writing plugin/interface for CAM/CAD software and I use this code to open a "SaveWindow".

```
public void Run(string theMode)
  {
     try
     {
        if (theMode == "SaveWindow")
        {
           string aPictureString = GetPictureString();
           StartInterface(null, theMode, CreateAndSaveTheToolList(aPictureString));
        }
        else
        {
           string aPipeId = GetRandomString();
           itsServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(aPipeId, PipeDirection.In, 1);
           ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.ListenToStream);
           StartInterface(aPipeId, theMode, "");
           StartNamedPipe(aPipeId);
           itsRefreshThread = new Thread(this.RefreshTools);
           itsRefreshThread.Start();

           if (!InitLogger(Path.GetDirectoryName(this.GetType().Assembly.Location)))
           {
              MessageBox.Show(//Secured code);
              return;
           }
        }
        itsLogger.Info("Run execute was successful.");
     }
     catch (Exception aException)
     {
        //Secured code
     }
     LogManager.ResetConfiguration();
  }
```

If there is an interface open and I click the plugin button again it opens another multiple one. How do I code to not to open the second one if the first is open.

Comment: The best is to ask support about it, as maybe you are missing some kind of "exclusive" plugin option. Otherwise you can try IPC synchronization, e.g. [named mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2186747/1997232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current situation is something like

```
if (condition)
{
    // Open your window
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

So every time you satisfy your condition another instance of your window is opened.

You can get around this problem by checking whether your window is already open like this

```
bool isOpen = false;

if (!isOpen)
{
    // The window isn't open so open it
    isOpen = true;
}
else
{
    // The window is already open so don't open it again
}
```

In this case the question is in the situations when your condition is satisfied but your window is open what would you like to do?

Simply adding the `isOpen` check to your open window path like this

```
if (condition && !isOpen)
{
    // Open your window
    isOpen = true;
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Will mean that whenever your condition is satisfied and the window is already open your code will "Do something else".

An alternative approach is something like this

```
if (condition)
{
    if (!isOpen)
    {
        // Open your window
        isOpen = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

This means that when your condition is satisfied you open the window if it isn't open and do something else if it is. Then your third case is the second "Do something else" path for when the condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: @Thanks Gareth. The problem has been solved. I did not explain it correctly but I figured out. Anyway, thanks for your answer.