# Maintaining single instance application

Tags: c#, mutex

I have been working on this application of mine and got this problem.
Running program through command line with different arguments opens different .exe process.

My question is how can i prevent from opening same file few times, and is it possible to send new command line arguments to already open instance of application.

Thanks.

Comment: Should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819773/run-single-instance-of-an-application-using-mutex

Comment: More helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904519/how-to-call-win32-createmutex-from-net

Answer (score 1):

There are standard .NET classes for that. Check out:

http://www.openwinforms.com/single_instance_application.html

http://www.smartasses.be/2009/04/24/single-instance-application-with-c/

http://www.google.be/search?source=ig&hl=nl&rlz=&q=SingleInstanceApplication&btnG=Google+zoeken&meta=